Replace value in Spark configuration
In the Spark configuration as follows, can we replace <datalake> with value from a secret such as {{secrets/yoursecretscope/yoursecretname}}?
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<datalake>.dfs.core.windows.net <sp client id>
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.<datalake>.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<datalake>.dfs.core.windows.net org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<datalake>.dfs.core.windows.net {{secrets/yoursecretscope/yoursecretname}}
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<datalake>.dfs.core.windows.net https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token

I have tried replacing <datalake> using value from an environment variable ${acctname} and secret {{secrets/yoursecretscope/yoursecretname}}, but neither of them work.


In the Spark configuration as follows, can we replace <datalake> with value from a secret such as {{secrets/yoursecretscope/yoursecretname}}?

Yes, it will work like that.
Follow the below approach where I am able to achieve your requirement by passing the storage account name through secret scope.
Give the configurations like below in the cluster.
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.{{secrets/<secret_scope>/<secret_name>}}.blob.core.windows.net "<access key>"
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true


Data from the storage account in the notebook:

It will work same for ADLS service principal as well. Make sure your container has anonymous access enabled in the storage account.
